# If x changes from x=1 to x=2 along the curve $y=x^2$, which of the following is equal to Δ(xy)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, slope

[Ans: 7, 19, 8]

It seem reasonable to use the literal change in y ($\Delta y$ = 4-1 = 3) * change in x($\Delta x= 2-1=1$)

Which should result in 3*1 = 3... But there must be something I'm not seeing here..? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point moves from $(x,y)=(1,1)$ to $(x,y)=(2,4).$ You have to compute the value of $xy$ at the second point which is $8$ and subtract from that the value of $xy$ at the first point which is $1.$ So you get $7.$

Comment: I see, so the question is asking for the change in $x_2 \cdot y_2$ - the previous $x_1 \cdot y_1$... damn.

Comment: @nvs0000 Yes. I thought maybe you were doing $\Delta x \Delta y$ which as this example shows isn't the same as $\Delta xy.$ [At least it looked like that's what you calculated.]